# DDP, Node, and Chrome Browserify

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, meteor, browserify, ddp

I am using the [ddp](https://github.com/oortcloud/node-ddp-client) and [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) packages in a chrome extension to talk via the ddp client to a Meteor app.

However, when I instantiate the connection, I am running across the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'connect' on 'WebSocket': The subprotocol '[object Object]' is invalid.
```

This occurs when creating a `new Websocket(uri='ws://localhost:3000/websocket', protocols={})`

I see a similar error at [How to access app hosted on meteor.com by DDP (WebSocket) protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857665/how-to-access-app-hosted-on-meteor-com-by-ddp-websocket-protocol), but the solution they had to change the port to 443 did not work.

Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Omit the second parameter, or change it to `[]`

Comment: When I do that, I get a `TypeError: Object #<WebSocket> has no method 'on'` when trying to open the socket with self.socket.on('open', func...)

Comment: Oh, I see. It has the methods onopen, onclose, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The protocols parameter is optional and must be either a string or an array of protocols as [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) (in your code you are providing an object)

Once this solved, obviously you will need to attach all the other mandatory callbacks, typically:

```
exampleSocket.onopen = function (event) {
  exampleSocket.send("Here's some text that the server is urgently awaiting!"); 
};
```

And the callback for handling the server's messages

```
exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log(event.data);
}
```