# Port number for meteor app

Tags: meteor, ddp

I'm trying to connect to my Meteor app using a DDP client, I've got everything down except for the correct port number. It was deployed to a meteor.com site. Does anyone know which port I'm supposed to use to connect to the meteor app?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried connecting on port 443 (SSL) or port 80 (non SSL)?

I just connected to meteoric-contacts.meteor.com using python and 
[python-ddp](https://github.com/hharnisc/python-ddp) as follows:

```
from DDPClient import DDPClient
client = DDPClient('ws://meteoric-contacts.meteor.com:80/websocket')
client.debug = True
client.connect()
def added(collection, id, fields):
    print '* ADDED {} {}'.format(collection, id)
    for key, value in fields.items():
            print '  - FIELD {} {}'.format(key, value)
client.on('added', added)
sub_id = client.subscribe('contacts', [], None)
```

That will then show you all the docs from the contacts publication triggering the 'added' callback.

See here for more info: 
[How to access app hosted on meteor.com by DDP (WebSocket) protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857665/how-to-access-app-hosted-on-meteor-com-by-ddp-websocket-protocol)

Comment: I've tried that already but for some reason the opening handshake doesn't start

Comment: just to make sure, I have to do "ws://<app name>.meteor.com:443/websocket" right?

Comment: Actually I guess it depends HTTPS is being used.  port 80?