# How do I find the wss URL for a meteor-deployed app?

Tags: meteor, websocket, ddp

I'm trying to connect via DDP to my meteor-deployed website at http://testsock.meteor.com . [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857665/how-to-access-app-hosted-on-meteor-com-by-ddp-websocket-protocol) has been very helpful, but I'm having trouble finding what my  URL is, which according to that answer should have the following structure:

> ws://ddp--xxxx-{host name}.meteor.com

How do you find out?

My meteor.js file is:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    }

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
      });

      Meteor.methods({
        test: function(){
          return 5;
        }
      });
    }
```

I'm using [pyddp](https://github.com/foxdog-studios/pyddp), and my python file to ddp into mywebsite is:

```
    import ddp
    import time
    import sys

    client = ddp.ConcurrentDDPClient('wss://testsock.meteor.com:443/websocket')
    client.start()

    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
            future = client.call('test')
            result_message = future.get()
            if result_message.has_result():
                print 'Result:', result_message.result
            if result_message.has_error():
                print 'Error:', result_message.error

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit()
            client.stop()
            client.join()
            break
```

Comment: I have been connecting to apps deployed on meteor.com using `wss://myapp.meteor.com:443/websocket`. Have you tried it?

Comment: thanks for the reply! but unfortunately "no handlers could be found for logger "asynico"" :(

Comment: I don't think that it has anything to do with the ddp connection. You should probably share the relevant code that, preferably, makes the issue reproducible.

Comment: Ah yes I just discovered that!! Not sure what's wrong with the code now but upon debugging, i see it can indeed connect via ddp. thanks!!

Comment: Did you use the URL schema that I specified or some other URL?

Comment: Sorry.. correction! I realize that wss://myapp.meteor.com:443/websocket was indeed not working.

I ran the script just websocketing locally (ws://127.0.0.1:3000/websocket) and everything works, but when deployed, i can't websocket in to meteor :(

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: I don't know `pyddp`, but I am using [python-meteor](https://github.com/hharnisc/python-meteor) and was able to connect to your test server.

Comment: great, i will try that! thank you very, very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to an app that is deployed to meteor.com, you can use the following URL scheme:

> wss://myapp.meteor.com:443/websocket

`wss` denotes the encrypted WebSocket protocol URI scheme, and it is run on port 443.